# How to make UDF to handle default arguments, together with other required arguments?

Tags: udf, xlwings, default-arguments

I have a python function which takes few required arguments together few default arguments, but when I tried as [fzumstein](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/305) mentioned it doesn't works as expected. What am I doing wrong?

```
def Doublesum(a, b=1):  
    return (a + b)**2
```

In excel:

```
=Doublesum(1)
```

This returns no value, i.e., `#Value!`. I  have installed xlwings version 0.7.2.

Comment: Have you decorated the function with `@xw.func` and imported them into Excel? Do other functions (without default args) work? Try to download the UDF samples from the homepage and try them first.

Comment: @FelixZumstein yes it was decorated with '@xlfunc'. yes functions without default args works.

Comment: What version of python are you using?  Out of curiosity, I just tried your example (with @xw.func) and it worked fine.  Trying to narrow down the potential differences.

Comment: @Paul I'm using python 2.7.11. I think may be this is the issue, I was not able to import UDF's if I import xlwings as xw and use '@xw.func', coz i get this Runtime error, Key error from line 197 xlpyserver. But if I change it to from xlpython import * and use '@xlfunc', it imports. I couldn't figure out  why but it has something to do with Anaconda!. How can i get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying a new install in a conda environment (as it looks like you have that). Try:

```
conda create -n xlwings-test python=2.7
activate xlwings-test
conda install xlwings pandas numpy
```

Try then doing `from xlwings import func`.  Then try the UDF [example](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/tree/master/examples/udf) -- i.e. download the two files (.py and .xlsm) and open the .xlsm in the same command prompt that you are using for your `xlwings-test` environment.

That worked when I just tried it (on windows). If you keep getting that stack trace about the keyerror then please post it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I created a new environment in the way you have mentioned above. But this I wasnt able to import udf's. Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment warning from Microsoft visual basic for applications.